# visual Studio operator += is ambiguous

Tags: c++, mfc

Using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprose for the first time, unable to make a simple keyboard handler.

I get this compilation error:

> Error: C2593   'operator +=' is ambiguous

in the following section of code:

```
void CAppView::OnChar(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

    CView::OnChar(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
    CAppDoc *pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    pDoc->d+=nChar;
    //Invalidate();
}
```

I have used the same code and it worked in MFC C++ application of  VS 6.0 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: And what is `pDoc->d`? Can you please try tocreate a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Also, please copy-paste the *full* and *Complete* error output into the question. Such error message usually have some more informational notes about why the compiler believe there is an ambiguity.

Comment: You absolulely need to provide the definition of `CAppDoc::d`. Whithout that we can only guess. A part from that it is really ugly to have a class member called `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the `d` variable is, but... Try casting it to a character:

```
pDoc->d += (TCHAR)nChar;
```

Comment: Thank you, the program worked.

Comment: @Breacher: You are probably wrong. This did silence the compiler, but the program may still be wrong. We don't know, since you haven't shared the relevant information yet. Either do that, or keep using a solution that may just fail in ways you have not expected. Using a `TCHAR` is the wrong solution, regardless the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @IInspectable If `d` is a `CString` I'm quite sure the cast is valid.

Comment: There are lots of scenarios, where the cast is valid. There are also lots of scenarios, where it isn't. You don't know, which partition you are in, since you have no insight into the code. My final statement remains: Using a `TCHAR` is the wrong solution, regardless of the problem you are trying to solve. Unless the problem you are trying to solve is to have your code compile for Windows 95, which we can preclude, since VS 2017 does not support compiling code for Windows 95.

Answer (score 1):

I remember vaguely that this used to compile a long time ago with old compilers:

```
CString foo;
foo += 65;
```

But with my Visual Studio 2017 I get the same error as you.

But this works:

```
foo += (TCHAR)65;
```

It actually appends the `'A'` character to the `foo` string.

So I suppose you encounter this exact problem.

Comment: Thank you, the program worked.
I tried to typecast nChar to Cstring before but it gavesome new errors.
What is TCHAR ?
 it is really ugly to have a class member called 'd'; Why ?

Comment: `TCHAR` is actually `char`, google it, too broad to comment. Why is `d` ugly? If I see `d`, I have no idea what this could be, but if it's called e.g. `typedchars` it would be more clear.

Comment: Er, a `TCHAR` is either a `char` or a `wchar_t`, depending on whether or not the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol is defined. Still, there is no conceivable reason to use a `TCHAR` in 2017.

Comment: @IInspectable as I wrote "too broad to comment". And using by using `(TCHAR)` it will work on any configuration. If I had written `wchar_t` or `char` there would have been 50% chances that the OP would comment something as: "it still doesn't compile".

Comment: It would *compile* for every configuration. Whether that would also work is a whole different question. 2 decades later, and you still seem to propose, that switching between ANSI and Unicode builds would be as simple as toggling a preprocessor switch. It ain't.